# jQuery noconflict and multiple libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple jquery libraries loaded, (cant change that, hosted ecom platform, with limited access to certain things) so I need to noconflict them.
current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('nav#menu').mmenu({
         slidingSubmenus: false
      });
   });
</script>
```

would like it to use a diff variable like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_11_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

so something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery_1_11_1(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery_1_11_1('nav#menu').mmenu({
         slidingSubmenus: false
     });
   });
</script>
```

but, not having any luck... 
thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: And what's the problem? Any errors, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe .noConflict() is what you're after here as all it will do is remove jQuery from the global $ namespace.

The problem you're having is that you'd like multiple jQuery versions to co-exist on the same page.

Your general approach of assigning to a variable is correct. Script load order is important. If your 1.11.1 version shouldn't conflict with an older version lets say 1.7.2 you need to ensure you load your version first, assign to a variable and then load the version you want to assign to the global $ last

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $jq111 = jQuery;
  // here we have set $jq111 to the current jQuery object which is 1.11.1
  // at this point $ and jQuery are also 1.11.1
</script>

//IMPORTANT: now you will load any plugins for 1.11.1 these are and should only be accessable with the 1.11.1 library but if the plugin uses the global $ you may have problems more on that later
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
  // at this point $ and jQuery are 1.7.2
  // $jq111 should be 1.11.1

  // to do something with 1.11.1
  $jq111('nav#menu')...

  // The menu plugin is loaded in the context of 1.11.1
  // To ensure subcalls to the global $ work we need to create a block
  (function( $, undefined ) { 
    // $ in this scope is pointing to $jq111
    $('nav#menu').menu(...)
  }( $jq111 ));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting? Have you tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery_1_11_1(function($) {
        $('nav#menu').mmenu({
            slidingSubmenus: false
        });
    });
</script>
```